# breadcrumb not appearing due to the navbar fixed at top

Tags: css, breadcrumbs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have markup defined in the page as below:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        </button>   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-pills">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Companies</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Help</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Help</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the page renders the breadcrumb hides behind the navbar. Any bootstrap way of fixing it? Or is this a bug?

Ps: jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/KNsYt/2/

Comment: Honestly I suspect this is a bug. I did try adding a class="container"  around the content, but it made no difference. Does it have to be the bootstrap way, or could you add a `class="pushdown"` to the breadcrumb ul, and `.pushdown {margin-top:50px}` to your styles?

Comment: @yochannah . Obviously, It's not a bug.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is clearly defined in [bootstrap documents](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top) itself as below:

> **Body padding required**
>
> The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add padding to the top of the . Try out your own values or use our snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is 50px high.

So, give 50 or more pixels of padding to the body to solve the issue. check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KNsYt/3/).

Make sure to include this after the core Bootstrap CSS.

```
body {
padding-top:60px
}
```